# Using Q Methodology arrays to cluster survey data

Tags: cluster-computing, k-means

I have factor arrays from a Q Methodology student and I have a survey with 400+ participants.  I used the same 42 opinion statements in each study.  In the Q study, all 42 statements are ranked from strongly disagree to strongly agree, and in the survey the statements were individually ranked on a 5-point Likert scale (strongly disagree to strongly agree).  I want to cluster my survey data round the four arrays I found in my Q study.  I entered the arrays into the survey data as if each were an individual who had answered the survey.  I've gotten stuck on how to cluster the survey data around my Q arrays and be able to tell which subjects (IDs) cluster most tightly around my four clusters.  I tried using K-Means, but I can't tell which subjects are in which cluster.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't really done a Q Method study here. In Q you ask participants to rank statements in a forced distribution rather than scoring them on Likert Scales. Once you've done this form of data gathering, the factor analysis is usually just varimax or PCA so no need for other clustering methods.